# Globalize.js API changes and jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, javascript-globalize

I'm trying to play with the examples from jQuery UI, such as [this one](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/). I would like to use the globalization functions (for a currency field, for example), but it seems that [Globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) has gone through a major API change, so that the code used in the UI examples doesn't work with the Globalize version I downloaded. For example, the jQuery UI depends on a Globalize.parseFloat function that doesn't exist in that version.

So apparently jQuery UI uses a legacy version of Globalize.js, but how should I download it? I couldn't find any information on that, neither on the API changes. I could download the JS files that are included by jQuery UI, obviously, but I was hoping for a "more official" solution.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that the Globalize 1.0.0-alpha releases are incompatible with the current jQuery UI 1.11.x releases.  I have successfully used [Globalize 0.1.1](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/archive/v0.1.1.zip) with jQuery UI 1.11.x.

[This](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2014/06/jquery-ui-1-11-0/) blog post from jQuery UI indicates that they are "...working on a full rewrite of the datepicker widget. The rewrite will feature a far simpler API that will make customizations a lot easier. The rewrite builds on top of the rewritten Globalize library, which builds on top of CLDR, a comprehensive source for globalization data.".  Hopefully, this rewrite will include more than just datepicker!

Comment: That's correct. jQuery UI is working the migration to the new Globalize 1.0 for datepicker (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/datepicker-globalize-1.x) and for spinner (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/spinner-globalize-1.x).

Comment: 2017 and Globalize 1.0 was released 2 years ago. Where is jQuery UI with this?

Comment: I see the [jQuery UI roadmap](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138038/Roadmap) (updated 6 months ago) references these changes going into 1.13.x.  That said, I don't even see a 1.13 branch in their repo yet, so it appears that it's going to be a while.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2016 already, two years later, but jQuery 1.11.x is still current (v1.12 in BETA). And I ran into this same issue for a brown-field project I'm doing. I managed to solve this thanks to the OP's analysis that jQuery UI indeed assumes the legacy Globalize version, and the solution of @wedgef5 to switch back to v0.1.1 of Globalize.

The OP did ask for an official answer. I guess there is none, but current best practice is to use a package manager. I use [Bower](http://bower.io/) which downloads the current version (now v1.1) by default. Assuming you did the same, you fix this in Bower as follows:

`bower uninstall globalize --save`

`bower install globalize#0.1.1 --save`

If you use a different package manager, something similar applies. After this code similar to [this example](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#currency) works :). Your `bower.json` should be changed:

`{
  "name": "yourpackage",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "globalize": "0.1.1" // Used to be: "globalize": "^1.1.1"
    ...
  }
...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to the [releases tab](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/releases) in the globalize github project? You can cross-reference the release dates of globalize and jQueryUI and make your best guess from there.